# Button Size cant be Resize

Tags: html, css

So , i want to make the button wider , not auto size to the text , i want it like 300px , i just try to add width on every class , but nothing seems working , is it because the button box line from text border ? i think its because the button from text border , so its auto resize with the text , am i right about it ? if that was the problem, can i click on a col-md-6 div for example ?

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: url(http://www.shukatsu-note.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/computer-564136_1280.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #06D85F;
  margin: 80px 0;
}

.box {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #06D85F;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #06D85F;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Pure css popup box</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<h1>Popup/Modal Windows without JavaScript</h1>
 <a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
 <div class="popup">
  <h2>Here i am</h2>
  <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  <div class="content">
   Thank to pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this window.
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  
</body>
</html>
```

**EDITED** Can i add href on col-md-6 class ?
**SOLVED** add display:inline-block;

Comment: `.button` in CSS doesn't have a width :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not need to add col-md-6 unless you want to use such space. Just add width property in the button class or in the custom class as per your need.

```
.button {
 width: 300px; 
 font-size: 1em;
 padding: 10px;
 color: #fff;
 border: 2px solid #06D85F;
 border-radius: 20px/50px;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 display:block;
}
```

Comment: so , is that because of a tag , can i change a tag to div ?

Comment: if you change a tag to div you can not use href , which in one of important aspect of the a tag.

Comment: can i use onClick rather than href ?

Comment: @RustRomaniaPlayer yes you can use onclick event both on a tag and div.

Comment: is there any better things to change size without change it to div ? i mean , still using <a>

Comment: @RustRomaniaPlayer on a tag you can add your custom class name and control the width as per your need.

Comment: The strange things is i cant add width on this ..
```
.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #06D85F;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: @RustRomaniaPlayer you can not edit css and add width in the .button class?

Comment: yeah , i just add width:300px; no effect

Comment: @RustRomaniaPlayer also add display: block;   or display: inline-block; as per you need should be okay I tested in in the jsfiddel. [example](https://jsfiddle.net/3uc6jmw5/)

Comment: @RustRomaniaPlayer if you wish you can vote up my comment and answer, that would be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

a-tag is an inline element so your height and width set are ignored. Add `display: inline-block;` and `width: 300px;` in the class `button`.

```
.button {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #06D85F;
    border-radius: 20px/50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
}
```